# See changes in svn from - last update to current working copy

Tags: svn, version-control, command-line

Using svn, is it possible to see the differences in a file from the state of the same of file in it's last last update?

For example I checkout a file - foo.txt - that file contained the text 'hello' I then add another line  - 'goodbye'. I would like to see that I had added that line.

How can I see between my file and the one that was pulled? I do not want the differences between my local file and the central file.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want `svn diff`:

```
I:\>svn status
M       sql\settings.ini

I:\>svn diff sql\settings.ini
Index: sql/settings.ini
===================================================================
--- sql/settings.ini       (revision 1322)
+++ sql/settings.ini       (working copy)
@@ -5,6 +5,7 @@
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 ; Main options ;
 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
+// Foo Bar

 [database]
 ; General database options
```